# How to iterate List<Tuple> in java

Tags: java, list, junit, querydsl

I am trying to write JUnit test case for controller class. Below Test case is running properly without any failure. But In that Test case I am checking expected result using Json path. I want to check `expected` String result with `actual` String result using `AssertEquals()` method. For that I want to know

How to iterate `List<Tuple>` result?  I want to iterate this  `queryResult` :

```
List<Tuple> queryResult = new ArrayList<>();
```

**AccountController class**

```
@GetMapping("/findAccountData")
public ResponseEntity<List<Tuple>> populateGridViews(@RequestParam(value="sClientAcctId",required=false) String sClientAcctId,
                                                     @RequestParam(value="sAcctDesc",required=false) String sAcctDesc,
                                                     @RequestParam(value="sInvestigatorName",required=false)String sInvestigatorName,
                                                     @RequestParam(value="sClientDeptId",required=false) String sClientDeptId) throws Exception {
    return  ResponseEntity.ok(accService.populateGridViews(sClientAcctId, sAcctDesc,sInvestigatorName,sClientDeptId));
}
```

**Junit Test Case:**

```
   @Test
    @Transactional
    public void populateGridViewsTest() throws Exception {

        String sClientAcctId = "5400343";
        String sAcctDesc = " ASTRALIS LTD";
        String sInvestigatorName = "Krueger, James G.";
        String sClientDeptId = "112610";

        QAccount account = QAccount.account;

        JPAQuery<Tuple> query = new JPAQuery<Tuple>(em);
        List<Tuple> result = query.from(account).fetch();   

        Mockito.when(accountService.populateGridViews(sClientAcctId, sAcctDesc, sInvestigatorName, sClientDeptId))
                .thenReturn(result);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/spacestudy/$ InstituteIdentifier/admin/account/findAccountData")
                .param("sClientAcctId", "5400343")
                .param("sAcctDesc", " ASTRALIS LTD")
                .param("sInvestigatorName", "Krueger, James G.")
                .param("sClientDeptId", "112610")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].sAcctDesc", is(" ASTRALIS LTD")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].sClientAcctId", is("5400343")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].sLocation", is("A")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].investigator.sInvestigatorName", is("Krueger, James G.")))
                .andDo(print());        
        }
}
```

**Account.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Account implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "account_seq_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "account_seq_generator", sequenceName = "account_seq")

    @Column(name = "naccount_id")
    public Integer nAccountId;

    @Column(name = "namount")
    public String nAmount;

    @Column(name = "sacct_desc")
    public String sAcctDesc;

    @Column(name = "naccount_cpc_mapping_id")
    public Integer nAccountCPCMappingId;

    @Column(name = "nindirect_cost_rate")
    public Integer nIndiretCostRate;

    @Column(name = "nagency_id")
    public Integer nAgencyId;

    @Column(name = "ndept_id")
    public Integer nDeptId;

    @Column(name = "sgrant_num")
    public String sGrantNum;

    @Column(name = "dstart_date")
    public Timestamp dStartDate;

    @Column(name = "dend_date")
    public Timestamp dEndDate;

    @Column(name = "slocation")
    public String sLocation;

    @Column(name = "sclient_acct_id")
    public String sClientAcctId;

    @Column(name = "ninvestigator_id")
    public Integer nInvestigatorId;

    @Column(name = "ninst_id")
    public Integer nInstId;

    @Column(name = "ntemp_account_id")
    public Integer nTempAccountId;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "ndept_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Department department;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name = "ninvestigator_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Investigator investigator;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name = "naccount_cpc_mapping_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public AccountCPCMapping accountCPC;
```

Answer (score 0):

to iterate list use for example for each:

```
for (Tuple tuple : queryResult){
     'put code and assertion here'
}
```

Comment: how to access `tuple.??`

Comment: using for each loop I am getting   `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.spacestudy.model.Account cannot be cast to com.querydsl.core.Tuple
`

Comment: then you have a `com.spacestudy.model.Account` inside that list instead of tuple, better check your code for some unsafe operations.

Comment: I updated my quation with code. I checked but didn't found any thing